# Azure SQL database stored procedures only running as SA user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an ASP.NET MVC app hosted on Azure. I use OpenIdConnect/Owin and Azure AD Integrated to authenticate. I have an error log table with a `UserId` column that only displays the SA username. I also have tables with `CreatedBy`/`ModifiedBy` columns that only display the SA username. These records are created via stored procedures.

I already granted execute access to my user account, but the columns continue to be set to the SA username. The only thing that I can think of is a connection string that is causing the value to only be the SA username.

How can I get the stored procedures to run as the user that created/updated the records to set the `UserId`, `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy` columns to its username?

UPDATE: I have narrowed down the reason for this. When I deploy the application to Azure, under Publish -> Settings -> Databases, connection strings are entered for the DbContexts. Currently, I have one as `Data Source=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=myusername;Password=StrongPassword123;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False`

I previously tried the following: `Data Source=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dbname;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;`, but got the error "The format of the specified domain name is invalid."

Comment: What is your question here? You don't ask anything.

Comment: You didn't explain where the `By` values come from. If you use a trigger to get the SQL user bug all connections are made as `sa`, then the columns will always show `sa`. Connecting with the root admin account is a very, *very* bad idea because any bug or mistake like eg concatenating input to generate SQL commands, can cause havoc or allow someone to do anything they want. Imagine writing eg `WHERE Name = '" + txtName + "'";` and someone entering `'; DROP TABLE Student; --`. People don't even have to know about this, they have scripts that try such things automatically to find what works

Comment: For the UserId column, the value is set to `SYSTEM_USER` in the stored procedure. For the CreatedBy/ModifiedBy columns, the values are set via triggers.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the stored procedures to run as the user that
> created/updated the records to set the UserId, CreatedBy and
> ModifiedBy columns to its username?

You don't. You pass those values into the stored procedure. Think of it this way: do you think `csharpdev` has write permissions on the Stack Overflow database? Of course not; the back end code passes your user id into the sproc that creates the record.

Comment: When using these stored procedures on-prem with Windows Authentication, those values do not need to be passed to set the correct values. It seems like there is a connection string that is making the stored procedures run as the SA user only.

Comment: without seeing them, all I can do is guess.

Comment: I narrowed down the reason for this and updated the post.